# How to filter values in a time series where they previously were larger than a specific value

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I am attempting to filter coral demographic data in a time series.  I have a set of corals that have been measured every 3 months.  What I want to do is a.) filter for all corals that **at some point** had a maximum diameter of 9, 10, or 11 mm and b.) remove corals that were previously **larger** than 9, 10, or 11 mm in previous coral censuses.  It's important to note that I do want to also filter for corals that are within the size range and in the next TimeStep, did not leave the 9-11 mm range because this constitutes 0 growth and I want to include those corals too.

I have created a sample database to work with.  Colony # 1 is an example of a coral that grew past the size range (9-11 mm) and then shrank back to 9.  Colony # 1 I want to be removed from the database completely.

Colony # 2 started out past the desired size range (9-11 mm) then shrank to within the range later.  I also want this coral removed because I need to ensure corals that are within the size range did not shrink to it but grew to it.

Colony # 3 is an example of a coral that grew to the size range (9-11 mm) and beyond without shrinking and this is a coral that I want to keep because it grew to the size range.

Colony # 4 is an example of a coral that started off above the size range and therefore needs to be removed.

Colony # 5 is an example of a coral that started below the range, grew into it, then later shrank back into the range.  For this scenario, I want to only include the first time the diameter fell into the range not the second time.  This is because the first time is natural growth whereas the second time is shrinkage and its resulting recovery (which I want to exclude or filter out).

Colony # 6 is an example of a coral that started in the size range for TimeStep 1 and then grew out of it in the next TimeStep and continued to grow after.  I want to maintain all measurements proceeding the first TimeStep in this instance so that I can calculate growth between TimeStep 1 and 2.

Colony # 7 is an example of a coral that started in the size range in TimeStep 1 and then remained in the range for TimeStep 2.  In this case (assuming that the coral does not shrink back to the size range later), I want to keep all measurements proceeding TimeStep 1 and 2.  This is a case where the coral had 0 growth from when it was first in the range and I want to include these corals in this database for analysis.

Colony # 8 is an example of a coral that grew to the size range in TimeStep 3, stayed in the range (10 => 9) in TimeStep 4, then shrank below the desired range then for TimeStep 6 grew back to the range.  For this colony, I want TimeStep 4 included for this coral because the coral is considered the same size between TimeStep 3 and 4 (because the size is still within the range of measurement error).

Colony # 9 is an example of a coral that grew to the size range in TimeStep 3, stayed in it in TimeStep 4 (10 => 9), and then grew above the range in TimeStep 5 and for TimeStep 6.  As such, this coral should have ALL measurements (TimeStep 1-6) included in the database because this coral never shrank.

Colony # 10 is an example of a coral that grew to the size range, stayed in it in TimeStep 4, then shrank below the range in TimeStep 5 then grew beyond it in TimeStep 6.  In this case, I want to include TimeStep 5 because I want to have a measure of shrinkage from the size range.  As such, only TimeStep 6 should be filtered out since the coral shrank below the size range (9 - 11 mm).

All told, I want code that filters this database such that if a coral at some point has a diameter of 9-11 mm but was previously larger than that range, was never at or below the range, or started below the range and never fell within it, they are removed from the database entirely.  Also, I am looking to keep any corals that grew to the range and then shrank back to it in the database while removing the second time it fell in the range.  I am looking for a general code form to be able to filter out these cases such that all corals in the database started below 9-11 mm and then grew into that range.  Thank you for your time!

#### Database

```
Data <- structure(list(Site = c("WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", 
"WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", 
"WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", 
"WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", 
"WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", 
"WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", 
"WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI"
), `Module #` = c(116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116), 
    Side = c("N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
    "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
    "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
    "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
    "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
    "N", "N"), TimeStep = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
    6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 
    2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Settlement_Area = c(0.75902336, 
    0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 
    0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 
    0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 
    0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 
    0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 
    0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 
    0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 
    0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 
    0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 
    0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 
    0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 
    0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336), `Colony #` = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 
    7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 10), Location = c("C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", 
    "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", 
    "A1", "A1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", 
    "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", 
    "A4", "A4", "A4", "A4", "A4", "A4", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", 
    "B3", "B3", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "B4", "B4", 
    "B4", "B4", "B4", "B4"), `Taxonomic Code` = c("PC", "PC", 
    "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
    "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
    "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
    "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
    "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
    "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC"), `Cover Code` = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1), `Max Diameter (cm)` = c(5, 8, 12, 15, 9, 16, 15, 13, 
    11, 15, 17, 20, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 20, 13, 16, 24, 22, 28, 
    30, 6, 9, 14, 9, 15, 19, 11, 14, 17, 17, 21, 24, 9, 11, 14, 
    16, 20, 22, 3, 6, 10, 9, 7, 10, 5, 7, 10, 9, 13, 16, 5, 7, 
    9, 10, 8, 13)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -60L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Site = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `Module #` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Side = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), TimeStep = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Settlement_Area = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `Colony #` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Location = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `Taxonomic Code` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `Cover Code` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `Max Diameter (cm)` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

#### Desired Database (filtered)

```
Data_2 <- structure(list(Site = c("WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", 
"WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", 
"WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", 
"WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", 
"WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI"), `Module #` = c(116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116
), Side = c("N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "N", "N"), TimeStep = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Settlement_Area = c(0.75902336, 
0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 
0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 
0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 
0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 
0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 
0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 
0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336), `Colony #` = c(1, 1, 1, 
1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), Location = c("C1", 
"C1", "C1", "C1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "D1", "D1", 
"D1", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A4", "A4", "A4", "A4", 
"A4", "A4", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", 
"C2", "B4", "B4", "B4", "B4", "B4"), `Taxonomic Code` = c("PC", 
"PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
"PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
"PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
"PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC"), `Cover Code` = c(1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `Max Diameter (cm)` = c(5, 
8, 12, 15, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 20, 6, 9, 14, 11, 14, 17, 17, 21, 
24, 9, 11, 14, 16, 20, 22, 3, 6, 10, 9, 5, 7, 10, 9, 13, 16, 
5, 7, 9, 10, 8)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -40L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    Site = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `Module #` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Side = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), TimeStep = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Settlement_Area = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `Colony #` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Location = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `Taxonomic Code` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `Cover Code` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `Max Diameter (cm)` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: It looks like the entirety of your reprex isn't pasted above. Since your question is so specific to your data, it's hard to troubleshoot without a ~minimally~ reproducible example.

Comment: Hello Matt I have updated the dataset dput so you should be able to see it now

Comment: I will recommend using the pandas package in python to process and filter your data. It is fairly straightforward in pandas.

Example:

`
import pandas as pd
p = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
p_new = p[(p['Message']>320) & (p['Message'] < 5000)]
`

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT #2:**
Just to summarize your filter-criterions as far as I understood them:

1. filter out every coral which starts with a diameter bigger than 11cm
   because you don't know whether it grew or shrunk into the desired
   range (coral #2 & #4)
2. filter out corals which never even reach your desired range (no example in your example data set)
3. filter out all timesteps after a coral starts shrinking again (as it for example happens in coral #1, timestep 5)

As you keep coral #1 in your desired output I assume it doesn't really matter whether a coral grows into your desired range or directly jumps over it. Is that correct?

CODE:

```
Data_filtered <- Data %>%
  group_by(`Colony #`) %>%
  filter(any((TimeStep == 1 & `Max Diameter (cm)` < 12)), # criterion 1
         !all(`Max Diameter (cm)` < 9), # criterion 2
         row_number() + 1 <= min(which(lag(`Max Diameter (cm)`) > `Max Diameter (cm)`))) # criterion 3

# test whether the filtering worked ok
all_equal(Data_filtered, Data_2)
[1] TRUE
```

This now results in the same filtered data frame as your desired output data frame (thanks for that - it makes things a lot easier!).

Comment: Thank you for your response Em!  If a coral reached the size range then grew past, I want all entries (rows) included for that specific coral.  If a coral grew to the range, then went past, then shrank to the range again, I want all the measures that precede and include the FIRST instance where the coral reached the specified range (9-11 mm).   I have also updated the database to include coral #4 and #5

Comment: Oh I see! I updated my code, but I'm having troubles getting the difference between coral # 1 and # 5...

Comment: The difference is that #1 never gets within the range of 9-11 mm in any quarter.  As such I want code to filter out these corals.  #5 is a coral that grew into the desired size range and then later shrank back to the 9-11 mm size range.  I want all data for the first instance that the coral reached the range.  This is because the first instance is natural growth which is what I want to quantify and filter for.  Whereas the second time the coral was within the range is an example of regrowth which I want to exclude.  Let me know if you are still confused

Comment: Ok, I get it. But as far as I can see, coral # 1 is in the 9-11cm range at timestep 3 as well as 5 again... But except for this confusion, I think the filtering should work now.

Comment: Em Laskey I actually have 2 more issues that need to be fixed.  I added 2 more corals to the database (Coral #6 & 7) that represent two additional scenarios.  For Coral #6, the first measurement (TimeStep 1) is within the size range I want (9-11 mm) therefore I want all entries proceeding TimeStep 1 to be present.  This is of course assuming there is not an instance where the coral shrinks back to (9-11 mm) in which as stated previously, I want to filter out the second instance where it falls into the size range AND all following measures for that coral.

Comment: For Coral #7, this is an example of a coral that starts out in the size range (9 mm) stays in the size range in the next TimeStep (11 mm) and then grows beyond the range.  For this case, I want to make sure that both measures (9 for T1 and 11 for T2) are kept along with all following measures.  This is because I want to maintain corals in the database that once in the range DID NOT grow out of it in the following TimeStep.  This stands for 0 growth (because my error in measurements are plus or minus 1 mm) and I want to use these corals for analysis.

Comment: So this means you want to keep all of your measurments for corals # 6 & # 7? Because that's what the filtering is actually doing. Sorry if I'm a bit slow in understanding your desired output - could you maybe create a desired output data frame and add it to your question?

Comment: Em I have added a new database (Data_2) that reflects what I am looking for.  I do want to keep all the entires (TimeStep 1-6) for both corals #6 and 7.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the desired-output data frame! I adapted my code again.

Comment: Hey Em I am so sorry for the continued queries on this post.  As I implement your code on my full dataset, I keep finding unique conditions that need to be accounted for in your filter code.  As such I have updated both the sample database and the desired databases adding 2 more corals to illustrate the conditions I need the filter to work on.  Let me know if you have any questions or confusion about these futher changes.

Comment: The main change is if a coral was 10 mm then 9 mm in the next TimeStep, that is not considered shrinking because the error in my measurements is 1 mm.  If it went 10 mm to 8 mm, that would then consititute shrinking.  HOWEVER, I want to include the shrinkage from 10 mm to 8 mm to calculate growth but all following measurements should be filtered out.

Comment: And to clarify, if a coral grew to the size range then in the next quarter shrank below it, like for example from 10 to 8 mm, I want to include the shrinkage from the size range (9 - 11 mm) but filter out all following measurements.